# Problem: How do I make these classes work?

Tags: c#, class

**Context:** I've been trying for the past 10 hours to get this code to work and I have no idea how to proceed.
My main issue is that I can't get any form of output, and usually only end up with a StackOverflowExceeded error in the debug window.
I'm really new to C# and I'm not sure what to do.

The program is *supposed* to add, remove, and display book information for people wanting to rent books.
Here's all I could do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyBookstore
{
    class Book
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int Serial {get; set;}
        public bool Status {get; set;} = false; //false means available

        public Book(string name, int serial)
        {
            Name = name;
            Serial = serial;
            //to do
        }
        public bool Available()
        {
            if (Status == false)
            {
                Status = true;
            }
            //to do
            //should return true if a book is available
            return false;
        }
        public void Rent()
        {
            if (Status == false)
            {
                Status = true;
                Console.Write("Book: '{0}' successfully rented.", Name);
                //A book can be rented if it's rental status is false
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("The book is not available.");
                //otherwise, the book is not available.
            }
        }

        public void Return()
        {
            if (Status == true)
            {
                Status = false;
                Console.Write("Book: '{0}' successfully returned.", Name);
                //A book can be returned only if, it was rented before!
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Sorry! '{0}' is already rented. System cannot remove a rented book!", Name);
                // rent status false means, it is available in the store.
                // Therefore, you should generate error message if some users tries to return this book.
            }
        }
        public void BookInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Book Name: {0}, Serial: {1}, Status: {2}", Name, Serial, Status);
            //Show name of the book, it's serial and rental status.
        }
    }
```

I thought I got this first part right, but I have no way of checking as there is no output.

```
    class Reader
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Book> books;
        public Reader(string name)
        {    
            Reader name = new Reader(name);
            //to do
            //initialize a reader object
        }
        public void RentABook(Book book)
        {
            if reader (name)
            {
                int Reader = 2;
                console.writeLine();
            }
            else if reader (name)
            {
                int Reader > 2;
                console.write("Cannot rent more books.");
            }
            //to do
            //user is allowed to rent maximum two books at a time.
            //issue error message, if users want to rent more than two books.
        }
        public void ReturnABook(Book book)  
        {
            public List<Reader> Reader = new List<Reader>();
            Book.Add(1);
            Book.Sub(1);
            //to do
            //return a book, means change book status and remove the book for the readers list.
        }
        public void ReaderInfo()
        {
            Console.Write(Reader);
            public List<Reader> Reader = new List<Reader>();

            foreach (var Reader in book)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(book);
            }
            Console.Read();
            //to do
            //show reader's name and the list of books rented by the reader.

        }
    }
    class BookStore
    {
        public List<Book> books;
        public List<Reader> readers;
        public BookStore()
        {
            public List<BookStore> Reader = new List<BookStore>();
            BookStore.Add("Object Oriented Programming", 1)
            BookStore.Add("Object Oriented Programming", 2)
            BookStore.Add("Object Oriented Programming", 3)
            BookStore.Add("Programming Fundamentals", 1)
            BookStore.Add("Programming Fundamentals", 2)
            BookStore.Add("Let us C#", 1)
            BookStore.Add("Programming is Fun", 1)
            BookStore.Add("Life is Beautiful", 1)
            BookStore.Add("Let's Talk About the Logic", 1)
            BookStore.Add("Let's Talk About the Logic", 1)            
            //to do
            //initialize book store
        }
        public void AddAReader(string name)
        {
            public List<Reader> Reader = new List<Reader>();
            Reader.Add(1)
            //add a new reader to the bookstore's reader list.
        }
        public void RemoveAReader(string name)
        {
            public List<Reader> Reader = new List<Reader>();
            Reader.Sub(1)
            //to do
            //remove a reader, therefore, first return all books(if any) rented by the reader then remove the reader.
        }

        public void AddABook(string name, int serial)
        {

            public List<BookStore> Book = new List<BookStore>
            Book.Add(1) 
            //to do
            // add a book object to the bookstore's book list.
        }
        public void RemoveABook(string name, int serial)
        {
            public List<BookStore> Book = new List<BookStore>
            Book.Sub(1) 
            //to do
            //remove a book from book store. Only allowed if bookstore already have the book 'available'!
            //Otherwise, issue an error message because the book is already issued by some reader!
        }
        public void RentABook(string name, string book)
        {

            if (Status == false)
            {
                Console.Write("This book is available");
            }
            else if (Status = false)
            {
                Console.Write("This book has already been rented");
            }
            //to do
            // A book can be rented, if it is available to the store and not already rented to someone else!
        }

        public void ReturnABook(string name, string book, int serial)
        {
            if (Reader = true)
                  {
                    Console.Write("Successfully returned")
                  }
           //A book can be returned by a reader, if he/she actually rented the book.
        }

        public void ShowBookstoreInformation()
        {
            Console.Write(BookStore);
            //to do
            //show bookstore information
            //first show all books that are already rented to some readers.
            //then show all books thar are available to the store.
        }
```

I realize this is a lot, but if anyone has any form of advice, it would be very much appreciated. I'm really, truly stumped.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you run the code in the debugger, it will point to the line of code where the SteckOverflowException occurs. But I doubt that you can even compile this code because it is full of syntax errors.

Comment: You should have a look at this duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71089859/i-have-been-stuck-on-debugging-my-code-for-a-book-store-console-application